# "type" object is not subscriptable when creating a list function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, typeerror, python-class

I have the below line of code and when i try and call this class object in the main function and run it. i get the error  "Type" object is not subscriptable.

```
class Order:
    customer: Customer
    items: list[LineItem] = field(default_factory=list)
    _status: OrderStatus = OrderStatus.OPEN
    id: str = ""
```

Comment: What are you expecting `list[LineItem]`  to do? This is using the list function, not  defining a list of LineItem values

Comment: This only works in Python 3.9+…

Comment: @OneCricketeer actually the `list[LineItem]` is a type hint that `items` is a list of `LineItem` objects and the `field(default_factory=list)` defines its initial value as an empty list.

Comment: @vaizki Not by default. I see no typing import. `list[LineItem]` is not the same as `List[LineItem]`, which I know what that does

Comment: @One Since Python 3.9+ it *is* by default.